# Laravel -weird output at top of every page and command

Tags: laravel-5

I tried to get an answer from the [laracast community](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/get-rid-of-text-at-top-of-every-app-page) but ended up not getting a response. I get the following text output at the top of every page or CLI command:

> > Skip to content Personal Open source Business Explore Pricing Blog Support This repository
>
> 3,019 22,483
>
> ```
> 7,384
> ```
>
> laravel/laravel Code Pull requests 0 Pulse Graphs
>   laravel/config/database.php eb7743f 11 days ago @dakira dakira allow
>   for setting sqlite database via env @taylorotwell @TGM @vlakoff
>   @dakira @marcanuy @pedes42 @jimmypuckett @GrahamCampbell
>   @david-ridgeonnet @SyntaxC4 @overtrue 121 lines (101 sloc) 3.84 KB
>   All of the files that may be suspect are available in the laracast discussion I posted. 
>   C4 @overtrue 
>   121 lines (101 sloc) 3.84 KB

BTW I used composer to install laravel.
EDIT routes.php file

```
    <?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('item', 'ItemController@index');
Route::get('item/create', 'ItemController@create');
Route::get('item/{id}', 'ItemController@show');

Route::get('welcome', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
Route::post('item', 'ItemsController@Store');
```

Comment: Most probably, the error could be in your routes file. Can you paste the full content of routes.php here? Also, if you could share the command you used to install laravel.

Comment: As stated in my question, I used composer to install laravel.

Comment: Sorry for extremely late reply. There's nothing wrong with routes file. Probably, it could be in your master template or some additional package you installed.

Comment: I checked the master page and nothing was there. How do I uninstall a package?

Comment: It's definitely one of the packages. Looks like laravel/laravel to me.. Weird. I'll try updating that package.

Comment: I think I got it. Can you please check the contents of this file: `laravel/config/database.php` ?

Comment: I don't see that directory in my file path. All I got is /vendor/laravel/framework/src and none of thhe folders have that file.

Comment: Can you please check `database.php` inside the `config` directory at the same level as the `vendor` directory ?